# How can i get customer data after registration?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, php, module, event-observer

I have the following code but it is not working.

vendorName/moduleName/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <module name="Vendorname_Modulename" setup_version="0.0.1" />
</config>
```

vendorName/moduleName/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
  <event name="customer_register_success">
    <observer name="customer_resgister_observer" instance="Vendorname\Modulename\Observer\CustomerRegister" />
  </event>
</config>
```

VendorName/ModuleName/Observer/CustomerRegister.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CustomerRegister implements ObserverInterface
{
  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
  {
    echo "Customer registered";
    $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
    echo $customer->getFirstname();
    echo $customer->getLastname();
    exit;
  }
}
```

VendorName/ModuleName/registration.php

```
<?php \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'VendorName_ModuleName',
__DIR__
);
```

Does anybody know why is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct but the namespace in your file VendorName/ModuleName/Observer/CustomerRegister.php is wrong

> namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

It should be -

> namespace VendorName/ModuleName/Observer;